# Is "must" ever grammatical as a past tense verb?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, past-tense, modal-verbs, auxiliary-verbs

I have seen uses of *must* that appear to be in the simple past tense. Sometimes these seem grammatical, but sometimes not. Examples that help illustrate my confusion:

> *He knew he must go to New York* - sounds fine to me.
>
> *He went to New York because he must* - sounds questionable.
>
> *Because he must go to New York, he bought plane tickets* - sounds completely ungrammatical.
>
> *He must go to New York* - grammatical, but with no other verbs to provide context, can't interpret this as being past-tense.

My question: is this past-tense use of *must* ever acceptable? Is it only acceptable in certain contexts - if so, what are those contexts and why?

(Note - I'm not looking for *had to*. *Have* is a different verb, so *had to* expresses the same meaning as the past tense of *must*, but it itself is not the past tense of *must*.)

Comment: The only time I've heard must used in a past tense is to say that one "must have" done something, which isn't quite the same construct. I would certainly say that for common English the past is either "had to" or it doesn't exist

Comment: Etymologically, "must" is the past tense of "mote" (as in "so mote it be"), so one wouldn't expect it to have a past tense itself. But just like the other "past tense" auxiliary verbs "could", "should", "would", "might", its meaning has become divorced from the fact that it used to be a past tense.

Comment: Like "had", you can always find a workaround using a verb that is marked for past tense: "He needed to go to New York" or "Because he [felt/knew] he must go to New York, he went".

Comment: @PeterShor: +1 This should have been an answer, rather than a comment, I think.

Comment: @alcas: +1. Could you consider adding if such a past tense form exists in other languages? The question seems otherwise redundant or at least limited in scope.

Comment: @Kris: I don't think it actually answers the question, which asks about the present-day use of *must* in the past.

Comment: I think the title of your question should have been: "Is the use of 'must' in a past tense grammatical?"... you would have attracted less "had to" answers :)

Comment: I would have used "have to" in all of these.

Comment: In your 3rd example it is not must that is incorrect but go

Comment: The third example is grammatically correct; it means “Because he must go to New York *in the future*, he *has already* bought plane tickets”.

Comment: I assume you don't want "must have" either? I guess "must have" has a slightly different meaning, now that I think of it.

Comment: I didn't even realize "must" was a verb until this discussion.

Comment: Must be.... (This doesn't sound past tense to me but I am not 100% sure.)

Comment: @UncleZeiv - good point as that's more what I'm asking anyway; I've modified the title.

Comment: @JonPurdy - I meant to rule out that interpretation. Imagine the sentence is in a context such that it's clear that "must" is supposed to be past; maybe it's a story about events that happened 20 years ago. "Then what happened?" "Well, because he must go to New York..." Given that context, must sounds worse to me than it does in sentence 2.

Comment: he went to New York because he musted. :)

Comment: related:[Deontic “must”, “have to” and “had to”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/446403/deontic-must-have-to-and-had-to)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Rarely, *must* is used as a past tense. Belshazzar, by H. Rider Haggard, has [we went because we must](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZBAx29Ff8_sC&pg=PA126&dq=%22went%20because%20we%20must%22&hl=en&ei=jgzgTrLoBsOZ8QOpt-z2BA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22went%20because%20we%20must%22&f=false), in a prose style which is perhaps deliberately archaic to reflect the ancient Egyptian context.

In this odd snippet, [If Thoreau went because he would, Hawthorne went because he must](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Qb02AQAAIAAJ&q=%22went%20because%20he%20must%22&dq=%22went%20because%20he%20must%22&hl=en&ei=TA3gTq2IAsOO8gOPw7DQBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC4Q6AEwADgK), one might say the author is "playing with language".

But here's Ralph Waldo Emerson with [What he did, he did because he must](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ZXM9AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA35&dq=%22did%20because%20he%20must%22&hl=en&ei=ZxDgTqDoMIr28gPQstXrBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22did%20because%20he%20must%22&f=false). I would not wish to say Emerson doesn't know his own language.

From comments under @Henry's answer, it seems something quite odd has been going on. Many people will know the archaic present tense [mote](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mote) because Freemasons & such still say [So mote it be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_mote_it_be) in a "ritual" context. Bizarrely, the *past tense* "must" eclipsed "mote" for *present tense* usage.  But in so doing, "must" somehow almost completely lost its ability to still be used as a past tense.

In spite of all the above, ordinary mortals in ordinary contexts today should stick with the standard position put forward by other answers. Use **had to** for the past tense.

Comment: Thanks! Was not aware of "mote". It's interesting that (according to that link) "So mote it be" means "May it be so", _not_ "It must be so".

Comment: @alcas: I think when you try to "translate" words like that, you risk finding a difference that isn't really there. IMHO, *So mote it be* can be just as accurately converted to *So must it be*. By bringing in "may", you're introducing a note of supplication to a higher authority (God), that's not really implied by "mote".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think there's a more specific denotational difference: "So must it be" means "It has to be like this", whereas "So may it be" means "Let it be like this." The former expresses certainty/obligation; the latter is a hope/command.

Comment: @alcas: You've lost me there. *So mote it be* and *Let it be so* are ritual declarative forms used by those with effectively "ultimate authority". They both really mean the same thing - *It* **will** *be so - because I'm the boss, and I say so*.

Comment: Note that it's only possible in a past sense when it's final in the clause. I.e, _We went because we must_ is OK, but _*We went because we must go_, unless it means _We always must go_, generically, and not _We were obliged to go, we had to go_. _Must_ by itself you can get away with, but add anything to draw attention to it, and you get ungrammaticality.

Comment: @John Lawler What about negation then? "I said he mustn't stay." If, as you say, "must+verb" can't be used, how can one convey the meaning?

Comment: @user1425: See [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=said+I+couldn%27t+go%2Csaid+I+mustn%27t+go&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) comparing past tense ***mustn't go*** and ***couldn't go***. Past tense ***must*** was more acceptable in the past, but it's gradually getting squeezed out.

Answer (score 15):

The reason that *must* does not seem to have a past tense in English is that etymologically it already was a past (or preterite) tense of *[motan](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/motan#Old_English)*.

Compare with the modern Dutch where *ik moet* means *I have to* while *ik moest* means *I had to*.

If you will not use *had to*, you can often use *needed to*, which fits your examples, or something similar.

Comment: *motan* and *mote* are the same verb, separated by several centuries.

Comment: @Peter: There does seem to be something odd about the idea that *present tense* "mote" disappears in favour of what by that logic was the *past tense* of the same word. From which I infer that during the transitional period at least, "must" must have covered both tenses, in which case there's no fundamental reason why it can't continue to do so.

Comment: @Fumble: *motan* was the infinitive, *mot* the 1st and 3rd person singular present indicative, *mote* the singular present subjunctive and imperative.

Comment: I guess you guys are right about "must" being somehow inherently past tense when we adopted the word. It still strikes me as weird in that it must have subsequently displaced "mote" for present tense, and later still, lost most if not all of its ability to be used as a past tense.

Answer (score 11):

The [Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org) devotes Section 147 of its "Grammar and Usage" chapter to *must*:

> *Must* denotes a necessity that arises from someone’s will [we *must* obey the rules] or from circumstances [you *must* ask what the next step
>   is] [he went to New York because he *must*].
>
> *Must* also connotes a logical conclusion [that *must* be the right answer] [that *must* be the house we’re looking for] [it *must* have
>   been Donna who phoned].
>
> **This verb does not vary its form in either the present or past indicative.** It does not have an infinitive form (*to have to* is
>   substituted) or a present or past participle.
>
> Denoting obligation, necessity, or inference, *must* is always used
>   with an express or implied infinitive [we *must* finish this design]
>   [everyone *must* eat] [the movie *must* be over by now].

But, to answer the question, I've found [this guideline](http://www.171english.cn/html/grammar/00065.htm) useful (it's not where I originally heard it, but its formulation is the same):

> Use *had to* in past tense **independent** clauses, and use *must* in
>   **dependent** clauses (usually noun or adjective clauses) when the sense
>   is that of strong obligation or strong probability.

Answer (score 10):

All modal verbs, of which *must* is one, are invariable. That is to say, they do not inflect for person, number or tense. There is no **musted*. If we wish to express the past sense of a modal verb, we have to do so by other means. In the case of *must* we use, as you have said, *had to*.

Comment: Some modal verbs seem to be past forms of others, such as *shall/should*, *will/would*, *can/could* and perhaps *may/might*

Comment: @Henry: Yes, there are obviously difficulties in trying to summarise something like modal verbs in a couple of sentences. We might, for example, say ‘I can play the piano now, but I couldn’t when I was younger.’ That, however, is not the usual meaning of ‘could’. It is more often used to express ‘unreal’ meaning, to seek permission and to make a suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

To express the past tense of *must* another verb is used, except when it used in the reported speech.

- reported speech

  > She said she must be going.
- certainty

  > That must have been the right restaurant. There are no other restaurants on this street.
- necessity

  > We had to have a permit to enter the park.

Answer (score -1):

You can express it like:

He went to New York because he had to.

He will have to go to NY.

and such on.

Comment: Did you read the part where I said I wasn't looking for _had to_?