# "I have to" vs. "I must"

Tags: grammar, tenses, modal-verbs, obligation

When would you use the following?

- I have to go the market.
- I must go to the market.
- I need to go to the market.

If I replace 'have' with 'had' would you have any other way to say it? E.g. I had to go the market.

Comment: You can say 'I needed to' or 'I had to'. You usually can't put 'must' in the past; see [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51023/is-must-ever-grammatical-as-a-past-tense-verb).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Have to* contrasts with *must* in that it usually expresses an obligation imposed by someone other than the speaker. *Had to* is the past tense of *have to* and may be used in cases where a past equivalent of *must* is required. *Need to* is used where there is not such a strong obligation, but where completing the action will satisfy a particular requirement.

Comment: I tihnk in some cases, "must" vs "had to" could operate a bit like "will" vs "going to", i.e. the modal expresses an 'on-the-spot realisation/reminder' of the necessity, as opposed to a 'planned' necessity. Or is that effectively an overlap with your notion of "obligation imposed by the speaker"?

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to add an important point re: the use of must expressing personal obligation.

The authors of the *Longman Grammar of Spoken and Written English* argue that

> the personal meaning (personal obligation) [of the modal *must* -
>   Alex B.] is most common in academic prose.

They also add that

> the rarity of *must* for obligation in conversation is probably due to
>   the strong impression *must* makes when used in face-to-face
>   interaction. *Should* and *have to* are less threatening ways to
>   express obligation in conversation.

cf. Swan 2005 361:4 or Martin Parrott's remark that "many people don't make this distinction" [*have to* for external obligation and *must* for internal obligation - Alex B.] (Parrott 2000: 125), see also Quirk et al. 1985: 226 note b.

Comment: Yeah, this is another fond wish for _Ordnung_ in grammar. Some people make this distinction, but most haven't ever heard of it, and never follow it. Everybody thinks there must be a rule for every variation, and so they make one up, and use it, and complain when others don't.