# What is the past form of the modal verb "must"?

Tags: modal-verbs, verb-forms

There are 9 modal verbs, and you can pair every two of them together to represent present and past forms, except **must**:

can ----› could

shall --› should

will ---› would

may ----› might

**must ---› ????**

So what's the past form of the modal verb **must**? Some people say it's **had to**, but I searched and found that **had to** isn't a modal verb, so what is it?

Comment: I don't think 'must' can have past form (like the others you mentioned) :/  **Must** = **have to** and past form of have to is **had to**. So you can use *had to* as the past form of *must*.

Comment: I would say "they musted the grapes".

Comment: Related: [Is "must" ever grammatical as a past tense verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51023/is-must-ever-grammatical-as-a-past-tense-verb)

Answer (score 6):

Well, that's not quite the way to put it. Those paired modals do not really mean 'Present' and 'Past', respectively. Or, if they **do**, then *must* has to be considered to be Past, with a Present form that's missing.

Here's how it works. In English, the modal auxiliary verbs have been formed historically from present and preterite stems -- that's where the 'Present' and 'Past' stories come from; **but** all the inflected forms based on them have been lost. So English modal auxiliaries are units, uninflectable and fixed in form, each with its own set of idiomatic, irregular, illogical, unpredictable, and constantly changing grammar and usage rules.

There is one context in which some of these pairs do function in time reference, e.g,

- *When I was young, I **could** do 100 pushups; now I **can** only do 99.*

But not all of them, and not usually; what could this sentence even mean?

- **When I was young, I **should** do 100 pushups; now I **shall** only do 99.*

Plus [most of the actual uses of modals](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Modality.pdf) refer to the present or future, not the past.

And, to top it off, *must* comes from the **Past** root of the modal, not the Present. German, which didn't lose the inflected forms of its modals, has *muss* as the present tense form and *musste* as the past.

- *Er muss schlafen.* 'He must/has to sleep'
- *Er musste schlafen.* 'He had to sleep'

Nobody knows why English didn't keep the present form of *must*, but it didn't. However, it doesn't matter in the long run, because `Present/Past` is the least of the differences between modals. [There's also the distinctions](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/modals.html) between `Possible` and `Necessary`, `Epistemic` and `Deontic`, and `Auxiliary` and `Periphrastic`, among others. Modals are complicated.

---

EDIT: To see just **how** complicated, here's the OED etymology, as promised in comments, for the *mote* (v) in *So mote it be!*, which is the only remnant left in English of the present tense of what became *must*.

> [A WGer. and Gothic preterite-present verb (wanting in Scandinavian): OE; mót corresp. to OFris. môt, OS. môt, muot may, must (Dutch moet must), OHG., MHG. muo/enticons/hgz.gif may, must (mod.G. muss must), Goth. ga-mo-macr.gift (it) has room, related to OHG. muohgz.gifa (mod.G. musse) leisure:-OTeut. type *momacr.giftamacr.gif.

The primary sense seems to be that preserved in Gothic, from which the sense 'is permitted, may' can easily have been developed. The transition from this to the sense 'is obliged, must' is more difficult to explain; it may have arisen from the use in negative contexts, where the two senses ('may not', 'must not') are nearly coincident.

Comment: '... idiomatic, irregular, illogical, unpredictable, and constantly changing'.  And we've only been in lockdown for 24 hours.

Comment: You say ***must** has to be considered to be Past, with a Present form that's missing.* Am I wrong in thinking that "Freemason / Illuminati"-style *So **mote** it be* is a (now rare elsewhere) example of the archaic "Present Tense **must**"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes. I'll append the OED's etymology for _mote_ v.1, which is interesting.

Comment: Dang, that sure is some murky etymology! :)