# The backshift of the forms of infinitives with modal verbs

Tags: modal-verbs

**Must** can be used in reported speech.

> 1. I told him that he must stay home.

However, what happens if we use other forms of the infinitive?

- What is Jack doing?
- He must be watching TV.

> 2)I said that Jack must be watching TV.
> **or** I said that Jack must have
> been watching TV.

Comment: *I said that Jack must have been watching TV* only applies if the original question and reply had been Q: *What **was** Jack doing?* A: *He must **have been** watching TV.* But note that this isn't the same as your first example, where someone was *obliged* to stay home. The equivalent for Jack would normally be *He **had to** watch TV*, because we don't like using ***must*** in past tense constructions. See [Is “must” ever grammatical as a past tense verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51023/) (possible duplicate?).

Comment: All modals can be used in reported speech. They can also be used in direct speech. They have no relation to this distinction. And paying so much attention to tense, a category that is disappearing and of no real importance in English, is a waste of time.

Comment: What is not a waste of time?