# what's the difference between must and had to in the past narration?

Tags: grammar

> At the same time, Alexei and those close to him recognized that they must also embrace the intellectual life of the West. They had to end the general ignorance and illiteracy at least among the boyars and gentry by introducing education

Comment: There's no difference. Either or both instances could feature ***must*** instead of ***had to***. BUT many people have "misgivings" when it comes to Past Tense "must" (see [Is “must” ever grammatical as a past tense verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51023/is-must-ever-grammatical-as-a-past-tense-verb?rq=1) as asked here some years ago), so even a careful writer with *no* such misgivings might not want to use it ***twice*** in the same sentence (to avoid "disturbing" his readers, even if he thought they were wrong to be bothered).

Comment: ALTERNATIVELY - perhaps the writer is taking the opportunity to "educate" his readers, by using BOTH verb forms in a context where it's contextually obvious they mean the same thing. Similar to the way a considerate writer will often follow the first use of a relatively rare term by some equivalent "definition" using different words, to save the less-well-educated reader needing to go and check in a dictionary.

Comment: I don't think writers get paid enough for that, @FF. Both _must_ and _had to_ were used inside the temporal scope of _recognized that,_ which means _must_ is not out of place in past tense (it has no tensed or infinitive forms, so it can only go as first auxiliary). It **is** interesting that _had to,_ in the same context, is obligatorily past -- _have to_ is out. Possibly because it refers to a present obligation and all those obligated are dead.

Comment: What is taught in Indian schools is that, MUST used in direct speech becomes HAD TO or must itself in indirect narration. She said, "I must qualify this time." She said that she had to (must) qualify that time.